# Can't sign approve transaction in Uniswap

Tags: erc-20, erc-20-approve

I created a simple Erc20 token contract, i'd like to make the token approval on exchange(uniswap) only avaliable for just the owner of the contract. Everything seem to work fine but when a user goes to exchange and click on approve button in other to swap the token, nothing seem to work. I can only see the error in the console mode.

[image]

Everything works fine when i switch to the owner address (owner can successfully sign transaction). How can i get the user to sign the approve transaction first before getting the error message ?

Here is my code for approve

> ```
> function approve(address delegate, uint256 numTokens) public override
>     returns (bool success) {
>   
>   if (msg.sender != _owner) {
>       
>      revert ("Sender not authorized");
>   } else {
>       
>      allowed[msg.sender][delegate] = numTokens;
>      emit Approval(msg.sender, delegate, numTokens);
>    
>      return true;
>   }  
> }
> ```

Comment: Well you cant, Uniswap wont let you sign a transaction if it knows it'll fail. Also why would you do that? Just curious

Comment: Potentially related: [How to bypass the pre-flight checks when sending a tx?](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/1767).

Comment: Thanks for your response Paul, plz how do i hard code or set gas limit in my contract.

Answer (score 0):

The code explicitly reverts when the sender it not the owner. Unless that part is removed there's no way for a user to approve a third party to use `transferFrom`.

```
  if (msg.sender != _owner) {
      
     revert ("Sender not authorized");
  } else {
```

A user can discard the Metamask warning and send the transaction but it will fail.